# Order by taking less time than max() in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle db and I am running 2 queries to find the maximum id from an indexed column.

1st query -

```
select max(id) 
from tableName
```

Explain Plan:

Plan hash value: 3791258597

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Operation</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Rows</td>
<td>Bytes</td>
<td>Cost(%CPU)</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td> SELECT STATEMENT</td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>1(0)</td>
<td>00:00:01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td> SORT AGGREGATE </td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>6</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>  INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)</td>
<td>Index Name</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>1(0)</td>
<td>00:00:01</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It takes 2.839 seconds to execute on a table having nearly 80000000 rows.

2nd query -

```
select id 
from (
   select id 
   from tableName 
   order by id desc) 
where rownum < 2
```

Explain Plan:

Plan hash value: 1514191988

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Operation</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Rows</td>
<td>Bytes</td>
<td>Cost(%CPU)</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td> SELECT STATEMENT</td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>27876 (1)</td>
<td>00:05:35 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>* 1</td>
<td> COUNT STOPKEY </td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>VIEW</td>
<td></td>
<td>84M</td>
<td>1046M</td>
<td>27876 (1)</td>
<td>00:05:35 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td> INDEX FULL SCAN</td>
<td>INDEX Name</td>
<td>84M</td>
<td>482M</td>
<td>27876 (1)</td>
<td>00:05:35 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It takes 2.6 seconds to execute on the same table.

When I see the explain plan of the 1st query, I see that it is using `SORT(AGGREGATE)`. Now I don't understand is that since the column is indexed, it should directly return the max value instead of using `SORT(AGGREGATE)` function.

Why `max()` is taking more time than `order by`?

Comment: Perhaps the query plan would enlighten us

Comment: Please show plans for both queries. Please don't attach a screen capture of a plan, but run a command `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select ......`, then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )` and append it's result to the question as plain text.

Comment: The added "plan" is **not** the output of `dbms_xplan`. How did you retrieve that?

Comment: I have added the explain plans.

Comment: ...why are you doing this?  What are you planning on doing with the answer?  Is `id` an auto-generated column?   If so, the maximum value is pretty useless, generally.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database/34975420#34975420) you can find some advice how to publish *execution plan* in a more compact and readable form.

Answer (score 1):

Both execution plans are fine

```
select    max(id) 
from tableName a;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |          |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE            |          |     1 |     6 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)| TAB_IDX1 |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here the index is accessed to get the MAX value (should require only few index block access). The `SORT AGGREGATE` is performed, but process only one value.

The second query ...

```
select id 
from (
   select id 
   from tableName 
   order by id desc) 
where rownum < 2;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |          |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                       |          |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| TAB_IDX1 |  3000K|    17M|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<2)
```

... access the index descendent and limits the number of rows to one. (again few index block access only).

Both plans are IMO comparable and *my question* is not why is one is slower, but why both take more than few milliseconds.

Please check the size and BLEVEL of the index.

I suppose the ID is NUMBER. My test give for both queries on an index with 96M response < 100ms.

Comment: This definitely looks like a testing issue.  The difference between 2.6 and 2.8 seconds can easily be explained by caching, server load, network, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's `INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)` I would have supposed it to be a O(log(n)) operation, both for MAX(id) and ORDER BY. Without an index, a Full Table Scan would be done with O(n) - but that's not the case here.

Maybe recalculating the table statistics might help:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME=>USER,TABNAME=>'tableName');
```

btw: is our `ID` a number or varchar2 or date?

Probably also have a look at this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9843506698920

Comment: getting MAX from index (which is sorted) is O(1)

Comment: Since it is an O(1) operation it should be faster than order by, but here just opposite is happening. Can you clarify why is it so ?